# My screen goes over and over again black

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchpad, trackpad

I'm new to Linux and I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My screen goes black sporadically, and when I swipe over the Trackpad it works again. I have a Dell XPS 15.

Comment: This is screensaver. You can turn it of in System Settings

Comment: Haha really? After 5 seconds? Well thanks! I feel dumb...

Comment: No the screensaver is turned off, i still have this problem.

Comment: What Graphics chip and what driver do you use? Also, are you on battery power? If yes, please see what happens when you plug it in.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a brightness and lock setting. You can search for brightness and lock in the unity search and change the time it takes for the screen to turn off to never if you do not want it to turn off at all.[image: brightness and lock]